# Can I partially suspend an angled climbing wall from my garage trusses?

Tags: walls, framing, garage, structural, truss

I'm planning on building a home climbing wall in my garage. I'm wondering about the structural integrity of attaching it to the trusses. They are 2x4s, 24" apart, and span about 30 feet.

This image shows basically how I would build the wall (the left one):
[image]

My wall will be 8' wide by 12' tall at a 45 degree angle (I have 9ft ceilings). Since this is a bit of an aggressive angle I'm concerned about attaching that much weight to my trusses.

I would also be adding some support from the middle/upper area of the climbing wall back to the garage wall, similar to this image: 
[image]

If that doesn't seem like it would be alright, how can I modify it to work? I was thinking I could add some 4x4 posts to the each side of the top plate, but I would prefer less intrusive options.

Would I need to reinforce the garage wall too? I can double up the studs if that's necessary

One last question, that original image is using 2x6s for the climbing wall frame, would 2x4s be alright as well? I've seen a bit of both on the internet.

Thanks for any advice.

Edit:
Here are some pictures of the attic I took a while ago, I tried to add an outline for where the wall will go (roughly). 
[image]
[image]

Here's an image to help visualize what I'm hoping the wall to be: [image]

EDIT: Current Plan

Per most recommendations I shouldn't attach much weight to the trusses. My current plan is to anchor the climbing wall heavily to the garage wall with joists at an angle (like the second picture but beefier).

For attaching the top of the climbing wall to the trusses I'm going to lay a 2x6 across about 6 trusses on top from within the attic and then bolt a 2x6 from within a garage to that one (so the trusses are sandwiched in between), that way I don't need to drill/bolt into the bottom chords at all.

I'll be doing the same thing about halfway between the top of the climbing wall and the garage wall and attach the climbing wall there as well. In that way whatever load is on the bottom chords will be spread out across a larger area.

Comment: 45 degrees seem awful steep. How are the 2x4's supported?  a 30' span needs something. Could you support the joists from the rafters? A picture of the garage ceiling would be nice.

Comment: Yes, did you actually mean 45 degrees? This would put half the load of the wall and its occupants on the roof system.

Comment: Yes 45 degrees. Here are some pictures of the attic I took a while ago, I tried to add an outline for where the wall will go (roughly). https://imgur.com/a/N7TWDXR

Comment: Here's an image to help visualize what I'm hoping the wall to be: https://i.imgur.com/qUrX4iz.jpg

Comment: Please inline your images into the question rather than posting links. External links can go stale making this question useless to future visitors.

Comment: So the big issue I have here is the non-unilateral forces.   Basically the wall and the weight of the climber isn't a big deal.   It is really the little twerks that the climber does that stresses the framing.   It will slowly move over time and then the weight load will come into play because of that.   I had a 300 pound water bag on a couple of cross pieces and a swivel rod in my garage...   4 months later went in my attic and saw the destruction - I went because I started hearing creaks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the type of garage ceiling you're looking to use. Not all trusses can be used for downward forces (say it keeps the walls from spreading) and if you're accidentally mis-describing them you could be getting some bad advice.

That said, assuming your climbing wall touches the ground the load will be carried there. Lateral forces on the side of the wall from 'pulling out' are supported by the cross bracing in ceiling. I'll see if I can find the article on design I read on the 'net about 3 years ago.

Edit: OK, going to give my non-civil-engineering view on this.
https://www.menards.com/main/buying-guides/building-materials-buying-guides/roof-truss-buying-guide/c-19431.htm

The example image shows all of the load being pulled downwards (compression) to the floor, and the ones nearest the wall providing tension to pull the rest towards the wall. You should have a large piece of anchored plywood or 2x8 back there to bolt into- lag bolting into your 2x4 sticks in the garage. Then you can attach multiple points to the 2x8 and the 2x8 can resist twisting the rear wall.

The bottom chord of your attic is in tension- it's to hold the walls from spreading. The upper chords are in compression and are carrying the load to the double sill plate around the base. The remainder of the web is stiffeners and compression/tension. Diagonal'ed boards in the attic prevent your roof from twisting around.

Just really limit how much 'weight' the ceiling is holding. If you do the example you've got, really emphasizing connecting it to the wall, it should be fine. Assuming of course the wall is connected to the floor somehow...

Comment: I've updated the original post with some pictures.

Comment: Bad news: Those bottom chords CAN NOT take the load.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for what I could do? Would adding the 4x4 posts I mentioned above work?

Comment: Per your edit, do you think I could attach it just to the wall? Similar to this board: https://i.imgur.com/NVT3k9t.png My only concern there is adding too much compression to the trusses

Comment: @Philll would you be okay if the angled supports went through the ceiling and on/upward to the second chord?   Or if there were two vertical bearers, one on either side ? (might make it difficult to get a car in the garage.)

Comment: Adding two vertical bearers on either side is my backup plan, I'm hoping to not have to do that. I edited the bottom of my original post with my current plan. I'll be laying down a 2x6 on top of my bottom chords and attaching to that from in the garage below, do you think it would be worthwhile to attach that 2x6 to the top chord? I feel like it would kind of be like adding in extra webbing.

Answer (score 0):

You have done an excellent job and this will be very strong (assuming a standard wall covering like dry wall or wood sheathing and not something odd like a heavy pseudo rock face).

Use #8 x 3" screws for the attachment to the underside of the trusses, (2) at each block and truss. No larger as this will compromise the truss too much, that member is in a state of tension. I suggest using the same screws everywhere, it's just easier than nails and you won't bang everything around. Get a powered driver tool of course.

Comment: seems you've got the PE and civil to better answer his question than mine- dunno what happened to all of the comments as they disappeared while I was typing. Looking at his photo of the attic the bottom members are dual spliced chords, and 2x4- I don't think they should take any additional weight over the 5/8ths drywall already on it. However the back wall (appears from the attic) to be fully supported, so should be able to resist any cantilevered weight off the wall. 250lbs @ 8' is pretty steep. Would you double lag-bolt to the wall to tie it together?

Comment: Re the trusses, they are designed for a dead load on the bottom cord, usually10 psf for things such as insulation and dry wall. The forces in the OPs design are more complex than simply downward force on the trusses, that is just one element. A lot will be taken up in the bending of the wall studs and other places. Wood has an amazing ability to redistribute loads. Wood is a lot stronger for shorter term loads. Wood has large safety factors. A lot of the vertical load will go directly into the wall anyway, as you suggest, even without the additional. More in next comment.

Comment: Having gone from the field to the desk path, I know, unlike many other engineers, what I/we would do in the field. I would say, that I like your thinking and you are close, and you, and I, used to error on the safe side, which is good, very good. In fact, I spend a lot of time working with contractors, often, when working with good contractors, my job there is about taking away the unneeded. That's where the training comes in as a PE, knowing where it's safe to tone it down, and where to beef it up

Comment: If the OP still has concerns, mitigate them by installing a 2x4 on the side of the truss from the point of attachment of the block to bottom cord up  to the nearest connection point of truss brace members and top cord. The only issue of your concern is localized bending in the bottom cord and that is highest at the middle between the brace connection points. It is FINE as OP shows, however, I know that there is concern especially since I'm just some internet guy saying stuff (good to remember!) and this should be a way that is obvious to address the concern

Comment: WHAT?!? That is the craziest notion I’ve ever heard of. You’re recommending adding a web member to a chord in double bending. You don’t know the location of the OP nor the snow load, so you could not have calculated the stress on any connections. Yet you’re recommending using 2 - #8 screws at each truss. That gives you only about 240 lbs. withdrawal at each truss. I think @isherwood is correct, it’s too small and like to fracture being 3” long. How can you say, “this will be very strong...”? Now you’re adding a web member to existing joint connections and could cause failure. You give no info

Comment: Where's the double bending? (not here) Do you understand what double bending is? In this case it would INCREASE the load carrying ability of the cord. This brace is a very common practice. The snow load doesn't matter as the truss is designed for this localize loading: IN FACT, if lots of snow, it's a beefer truss and this new load is even less important, so it HELPS. Where do you get 240#s? That's too low by a margin. Did you apply load factors? What info do you want, similar to what you've provided? Which is? If you want a calc package, then go to your local engineer

Comment: You give no info about which joint connection or how far from the joint is acceptable. This is not acceptable. You made such a big deal that your a structural engineer to @isherwood yet you have overlooked some major issues: 1) double bending, 2) live load conditions, 3) weight of climbing wall material, 4) species and grade of truss members, 5) overload existing steel plate connectors, etc. that I doubt if your a licensed structural engineer. Structural engineers I know, qualify every item. They don’t just say, “it will be very strong” and then come back later and add web members.

Comment: I really don't understand your issue with me or my posts but your assumption that I haven't considered these items is just pure speculation that also happens to be wrong. You don't understand double bending to understand that it's not an issue, there is nothing to show there. You don't seem to understand how live loads affect the situation or how they are applied. I did consider the weight, it's in my post to keep it to dry wall or wood sheathing. Species and grade of the truss doesn't matter. Use HF#2 or better ok? The plate connectors are not a fail point for this situation. But considered

Comment: Re which joint connection, I said the nearest so I did in fact answer that question. How far? It doesn't matter, by the time you got too far away, it would be obvious that its not at the joint any more. All this despite this brace is a feel good to appease you anyway, it's not necessary, as I have already noted when I mentioned it.

Comment: @Ack You don’t understand how a truss is designed and you don’t understand double bending. The original truss was designed to span 30’ which puts the bottom chord in tension. Now you’re attaching a load to the bottom chord, which puts the chord in compression AND tension. This load you’re adding. Is 1) unknown, 2) is ADDED to the tension of the existing chord, 3) is adding an unknown load to the existing joint connections, etc.   In addition, you’re suggesting to add a new web member to the existing chords and joints, which you do not know their load capacity/design.

Comment: You have misunderstood my comment regarding live load. You think I’m referring to the bottom chord, but I’m referring to the top chord which could be 30-40 psf depending on the OP’s location, which you don’t seem to understand or care. That load added to the wall load could cause the existing joints to fail...especially with the OP’s design idea.

Comment: I understood what you were suggesting and even with the additional explanation you're still wrong. The SNOW load (live loads are different, they don't normally occur on roofs, though there is a construction load that is considered) can be much higher than that, I've done designed into the 300+ psf in the Cascades and around Tahoe. The loads are fine, there isn't an issue here. As I've tried to explain to you, the higher the SL the more that this design is ok as I've noted, and how I've noted. Thank you

Comment: So when you say it “will be obvious when it’s not at the joint anymore “, does that mean 2”, 6”, 10” away from the joint or from the steel plate connector? You say the brace “is a feel good to appease you anyway, it’s not necessary”. You don’t realize you’re changing the design of the truss and it’s connections. So you think it’s a feel good idea, but you don’t know you’ve perhaps over stressed the joints...depending on the live load (snow load) and the actual load of the climbing wall. In order to know this info, you’d need to ask the OP, which you didn’t. That’s why I question your license.

Comment: @Ack Btw, shooting from the hip is not ok for this site. Claiming to be a structural engineer gives a certain credibility and can severely impact the OP’s decision. (As you know, you’re held to a higher standard.) after all this, you never said “check with a structural engineer.” Instead you said “it’ll be very strong.” and you didn’t know or understand the loads involved for this rather unusual situation.

Comment: @Ack Do you mean dropping a support 2x4 for the overhang? (or 4x4, or 2x2x4, or whatever)? I could see that completely for stability (and the climbing center near me has a 2x12 engineered beam that is supported on the ends by a small post- that handles all of the overhang weight).

Comment: @J.Hirsch I think that you're referring to a post and beam supported by the floor (floor joists) and that is not what I mean. The OP has added some pictures of the trusses system from within the attic and outlined where the attachments would be located. Based on this picture, the attachment would be made very near a connection point of the and therefore the 2x4 brace I offered not necessary. The brace was for additional bottom cord mid span between connection points.

Answer (score 0):

Your attic is totally capable of holding the walls and a climber's weight.   However it cannot deal with a moving climber and I don't see how this would ever be legal (could void home owner's policy) without sign-off from engineer and city.

If you are going to do it no matter what then what you need to focus is cross lateral support in the attic.   I would put some intensive blocking, I would add at least 2x4 stirrups across the top and would go with plywood over that but I might skip that due to weight.

Comment: Wood can handle dynamic weight much better than static loads, it is one of it's unique properties. For impact loads, the design strength that we use is 2x that of consistent dead loads. Yes, that is correct, -double-